# Integrating Microsoft Bot v4 with ServiceNow

Tags: active-directory, botframework, single-sign-on, microsoft-teams, servicenow-rest-api

I have office 365 account. Hence I get re-directed to ServiceNow portal without asking for user credentials.

Likewise, my Bot (v4) is hosted in MS Teams. **What are the ways to initiate REST calls from Bot to ServiceNow without asking my credentials? Like SSO.**

My ServiceNow instance does not allow client_credentials grant type and hence need to work on other grant-types which require user password.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific tutorial for integrating a bot with ServiceNow. You can make use of the REST API which is documented [here](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/london-application-development/page/build/applications/concept/api-rest.html) to address your purpose. Refer to the following documentations as well to get more information about the ServiceNow [SSO](https://www.manageengine.com/products/self-service-password/step-by-step-guide-for-servicenow-single-sign-on.html) and Azure Bot Service [authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp).